# SEO: Google fetch returns blank page (but rendered HTML seems correct)

Tags: .htaccess, fetch

I usually find all the answers to my question but this time I could not find any. This if actually the first time I post on stackoverflow!
Here is my problem.

The root of my website: "www.example.com" returns a blank (not empty) page when I use Google Webmaster Tools to fetch my website. When I look at the rendered HTML, it is exactly what it should be, but the preview of the page is just blank.

All the other pages of my website like "www.example.com/sample_page.html" seem to give the proper preview though. I have even tried to make a redirection (htaccess) of the root domain "www.example.com" to "www.example.com/sample_page.html" but it also gives a blank preview.

I use cached HTML files so it does not have anything to do with enabled JS or whatsoever. Furthermore, like I told you, the rendered HTML seems OK it's just the preview that does not return anything.

Any hint is greatly appreciated as I have been trying to find a solution since a few weeks now.

Comment: Now, a better forum for this question would be the Webmasters stack exchange, and to tag your post with **seo**: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo